# How to get name of child constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have a class with prototype method `printConstructorName` which prints the name of the constructor:

```
function Parent(){
}

Parent.prototype.printConstructorName = function(){
   console.log(this.constructor.name);
};

var parent = new Parent();
parent.printConstructorName(); // It gets 'Parent'.
```

A class `Child` inherits the `Parent` through the prototype:

```
function Child()
{
}

Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;

var child = new Child();
child.printConstructorName(); // It gets 'Parent', but 'Child' is necessary.
```

How to get the name of Child's constructor through the Parent's prototype method?

Comment: Please notice that `name` is a non-standard property of functions and should not be used for anything else than debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the `Parent`s prototype object to `Child.prototype` - which means that every child instance inherits from the same thing as all parent instances, and of course they inherit the same `constructor` property that way.

Instead, create a new object for the `Child.prototype`, inheriting from the `Parent.prototype`, and you can overwrite the `constructor` property then:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype, {
    constructor: {value: Child, configurable: true}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/q6KQb/3/)

The inheritance pattern is the problem. Here's the quick fix:

```
function inherits(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};

function Parent(){}

Parent.prototype.printConstructorName = function(){
   return this.constructor.name;
};

var parent = new Parent();
console.log(parent.printConstructorName()); // It gets 'Parent'.

function Child() {
    Parent.call(this);
};
inherits(Child, Parent);

var child = new Child();
console.log(child.printConstructorName()); // It gets 'Child'.
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not actually working. You forgot to actually name the `inherits` function at the top.

Comment: @alex23 Faster than me :P +1

Answer (score 3):

Your inheritance mechanism is clearly wrong. The way you've done it, if you add a property to Child.prototype, all Parent objects will also get it...

You might want an `inherit` function something like this:

```
inherit = (function() {
    function F() {};
    return function(parent, child) {
        F.prototype = parent.prototype;
        child.prototype = new F();
        child.prototype.constructor = child;
    };
}());
```

which you can then use this way:

```
function Parent() {
}

Parent.prototype.printConstructorName = function(){
   console.log(this.constructor.name);
};

var parent = new Parent();
parent.printConstructorName();  // Parent

function Child() {
}

inherit(Parent, Child);

var child = new Child(); // Child
child.printConstructorName();
```

Comment: The `inherit` function itself is inside a closure, which contains the function `F`, but using it introduces no additional closures into other code.  (The `parent` and `child` don't collect any references to such closures.)

Answer (score 1):

When you're extending an existing constructor, you should set the child prototype to an instance of the parent class, so that changes to the child prototype don't affect the parent prototype.

Then you can simply override the `constructor` such that it points to the correct function.

```
function Parent() {
    ....code...
}

Parent.prototype.printConstructorName = function () {
    console.log(this.constructor.name);
};

function Child() {
    ...code...
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

p = new Parent();
p.printConstructorName(); //Parent

c = new Child();
c.printConstructorName(); //Child
```

Answer (score 1):

Write an extend function, something like:

```
__extend = function(child, sup) {
    for (prop in sup.prototype) {
        child.prototype[prop] = sup.prototype[prop];
    };
};
```

And then you call it instead of doing the `prototype = new parent` trick - like:

```
var Parent = function() {}
Parent.prototype.name = function() { return "name" };

var Child = function() {}
__extend(Child, Parent);
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cmg4A/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should override the printConstructorName in Child :D.

Comment: Thank you. But I need one method for all children)